# "ORA-00922: missing or invalid option" SQL create table error

Tags: sql, oracle

```
    CREATE TABLE sales_invoice -- missing or invalid option
        (sales_invoice_no                 NUMBER(6) NOT NULL
            CONSTRAINT sales_invoice_no_pk PRIMARY KEY
       , cust_id                         NUMBER(6) NOT NULL
       ,   CONSTRAINT sales_cust_invoice_fk FOREIGN KEY (cust_id)
            REFERENCES customer(cust_id))   
       , art_id                           NUMBER(6) NOT NULL
       ,   CONSTRAINT art_invoice_fk FOREIGN KEY (art_id)
            REFERENCES art_sale(art_id)
       , sales_emp_id                    NUMBER(6) NOT NULL
       ,    CONSTRAINT sales_invoice_emp_fk (sales_emp_id)
            REFERENCES sales_emp(emp_id)
       , manager_emp_id                   NUMBER(6)
       ,   CONSTRAINT manager_invoice_emp_fk (manager_emp_id) 
            REFERENCES manager_emp(emp_id)
       , sales_invoice_amount             NUMBER (10)
            CONSTRAINT sales_amount_check CHECK (sales_invoice_amount > 0 ));
```

I'm getting this error when I try to run this. I'm trying to create a table that draws from several other tables and print it as a sales invoice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found a problem - I was missing FOREIGN KEY before sales_emp_id and manager_emp_id. But I added those and still getting missing or invalid iotion

Comment: We really cannot help you debug this remotely, unfortunately. And you haven't provided enough information ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formatting makes it harder to spot errors I think. I reformatted your code and found an extra **")"** after your "sales_cust_invoice_fk" constraint. Here is the reformatted code:

```
 CREATE TABLE sales_invoice (
sales_invoice_no    NUMBER(6) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT sales_invoice_no_pk PRIMARY KEY
cust_id         NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
art_id          NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
sales_emp_id        NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
manager_emp_id      NUMBER(6),
sales_invoice_amount    NUMBER (10),
CONSTRAINT sales_cust_invoice_fk FOREIGN KEY (cust_id) REFERENCES customer(cust_id), 
CONSTRAINT art_invoice_fk FOREIGN KEY (art_id) REFERENCES art_sale(art_id),
CONSTRAINT sales_invoice_emp_fk (sales_emp_id) REFERENCES sales_emp(emp_id),
CONSTRAINT manager_invoice_emp_fk (manager_emp_id) REFERENCES manager_emp(emp_id),
CONSTRAINT sales_amount_check CHECK (sales_invoice_amount > 0 )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the query

```
CREATE TABLE sales_invoice 
        (sales_invoice_no                 NUMBER(6) NOT NULL
            CONSTRAINT sales_invoice_no_pk PRIMARY KEY
       , cust_id                         NUMBER(6) NOT NULL
       ,   CONSTRAINT sales_cust_invoice_fk FOREIGN KEY (cust_id)
            REFERENCES customer(cust_id)   
       , art_id                           NUMBER(6) NOT NULL
       ,   CONSTRAINT art_invoice_fk FOREIGN KEY (art_id)
            REFERENCES art_sale(art_id)
       , sales_emp_id                    NUMBER(6) NOT NULL
       ,    CONSTRAINT sales_invoice_emp_fk FOREIGN KEY (sales_emp_id)
            REFERENCES sales_emp(emp_id)
       , manager_emp_id                   NUMBER(6)
       ,   CONSTRAINT manager_invoice_emp_fk FOREIGN KEY (manager_emp_id) 
            REFERENCES manager_emp(emp_id)
       , sales_invoice_amount             NUMBER (10)
            CONSTRAINT sales_amount_check CHECK (sales_invoice_amount > 0 ));
```